# Using robocopy to copy files/folders with spaces is insane

Tags: windows, robocopy

I've looked at a dozen articles regarding how to copy a source and destination containing spaces using robocopy.  Nothing I've tried works!  I've tried a mind numbing number of double quotes, single quotes, with and without spaces after the names as shown below, nothing I've tried works!  I've tried adding a *.* after the target, nada.  Considering that many solutions I've read do work, I'm wondering if it's my version of robocopy or windows?  I'm currently on Windows 10 Enterprise version 1803.

```
robocopy "C:\Users\zbernie\Desktop\1 Source Folder with Spaces\bernie3_firsts - Copy.txt " "C:\Users\zbernie\Desktop\1 Target Folder With Spaces " /e
```

Comment: This is a "how do I use my computer?" question not a software development question.  Please use SuperUser for questions about using software written by other people.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently you cannot specify a file name as the source.  Using folders as source and targets, and THEN the files to be copied worked.

```
robocopy "C:\Users\zbernie\Desktop\1 Source Folder with Spaces" "C:\Users\zbernie\Desktop\1 Target Folder With Spaces" *files* /e
```

Comment: This is at the very top of the robocopy documentation, so it should have been very evident.